# What does the default WPF app manifest look like?

Tags: c#, wpf, manifest

we have a WPF application that currently uses the default manifest setting: "Embed manifest with default settings" and it works for us. We now need to add a custom manifest in order to use a third-party library that requires a setting in there. But we don't want to risk there being any other differences from before. And that brings the question. Is there a way to know what that default manifest that we are using now actually looks like so we can add to it? I have checked the obj and bin folders but didn't find anything in there and internet search hasn't really brought up much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default manifest that is embedded into the assembly when you build the app looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="YourAppName.app"/>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

You can extract it using a decompiler.